# Send custom deploy message to slack from heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, slack-api

I am able to setup a deploy HTTP hook that calls the Slack API on every deploy of my Heroku app.

```
$ heroku addons:create deployhooks:http
```

How can you customize the deploy message that this sends?

Comment: take a look at this: https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder

Comment: It seems that you can't. In Email hook you can use variables like `{{git_log}}` , `{{user}}` etc but they don't seem to work with HTTP deploy hook. Sad, Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Deploy Hooks is set to sun set February 17, 2023. To keep your integrations working, you can replace Deploy Hooks with [Activity To Go](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/activitytogo).

Hope this helps.